# Is there an R function to find the minima of an dependent variable based on several mixed type independent variables?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a large dataframe consisting of 8 independent variables and one dependent variable (and thousands of observations). A small sample is the below:

```
df <- structure(list(iv_1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L
), iv_2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), iv_3 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), iv_4 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L), iv_5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), iv_6 = c(0.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9, 0.7, 
0.4, 0.2), iv_7 = c(1, 1, 0.1, 0, 0.5, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 1), 
    iv_8 = c(0.14, 0.19, 0.09, 0.04, 0.09, 0.19, 0.05, 0.16, 
    0.12, 0.03), dv = c(350, 350, 5, 350, 5, 5, 5, 350, 2, 10
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

iv_1 through to iv_5 are categorical; iv_6 to iv_8 are theoretically floating points, although, have been discretised with a precision of .1 or .01.

Given my dataset, I want to find the joint combination of parameter settings which, on average, minimises the dependent variable.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Note, before, I was trying to do this on the fly with optim(). However, this doesn't work in my case because the values need to be precomputed, and hence, we can't let optim iteratively explore the parameter space by generating its own new estimates: it needs to use what it has in the dataframe. Also, optim can't used mixed type data, AFAIK.

Comment: Why not use regression? Or, if you need to use values in the data frame, what about the values of the parameters where the dv is empirically at its minimum?

Comment: Incidentally, I did fit a glm to the data, but how can I use this to find the combination of parameters which minimises the DV (on average)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to tackle this. First, do a regression with all the relevant variables:

```r
mod <- glm(dv ~., data = df)

summary(mod)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = dv ~ ., data = df)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8  
#>  52.583    6.242   64.637  -23.282   48.920  -63.897   -6.242   23.282  
#>       9       10  
#> -67.130  -35.113  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept)  1422.19    1020.15   1.394    0.396
#> iv_1         -544.66     176.81  -3.081    0.200
#> iv_2           74.14     159.09   0.466    0.722
#> iv_3         -396.31     380.20  -1.042    0.487
#> iv_4          -80.55      57.45  -1.402    0.394
#> iv_5          -53.88      83.98  -0.642    0.637
#> iv_6         -201.98     338.64  -0.596    0.658
#> iv_7          323.35     181.56   1.781    0.326
#> iv_8        -3378.75    3551.88  -0.951    0.516
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 20320.41)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 285142  on 9  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance:  20320  on 1  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 124.55
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

Notice that some of the variables have negative coefficients and some have positive coefficients. Since you wish to minimize the dv, all you need to do is to find the largest value in any column with a negative coefficient, and the smallest value in any column with a positive coefficient.

```r
res <- as.data.frame(Map(function(a, b) if(a < 0) max(b) else min(b),
    a = coef(mod)[-1], b = model.frame(mod)[-1]))

res
#>   iv_1 iv_2 iv_3 iv_4 iv_5 iv_6 iv_7 iv_8
#> 1    1    0    1    8    3  0.9    0 0.19
```

We can show that these values produce a much smaller value for dv than any existing combination in your data frame:

```
df$dv
#> [1] 350 350   5 350   5   5   5 350   2  10

predict(mod)
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 297.41698 343.75813 -59.63687 373.28234 -43.92043  68.89748  11.24187 326.71766 
#>         9        10 
#>  69.13018  45.11266

predict(mod, newdata = res)
#>         1 
#> -1148.537
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. A few questions/things to mention 1) this doesn't seem to work if the categorical columns are cast as factors, but if left numeric, is the effect the same? 2) 0 is the lowest possible value of the dependent variable, yet the extrapolation of the model predicts a negative number. Is this a problem? 3) in my model, there are several significant interactions between the IVs. Is this taken into account? (I assume so)

Comment: Also, when I predict on my actual model, built on my full dataset, the lowest predicted value is 2.90, which is not the lowest possible value of the dependent variable (there are many cases of 0 and 1). And then when I predict using the newdata (i.e., stored in your var res), I get a value of 1.9, which again is not the lowest possible value.

Comment: @eartoolbox the answers are 1) No, this won't work as-is with factor levels unless they have only 2 levels, though it could be modified to incorporate them. 2) This combination of ivs predicts this falue of the dv with the given model. It sounds like your dv has count data, in which case a poisson glm would be the right model. The predicted value of dv will always be positive in this case. 3) I'm afraid interactions are not accounted for in this specific model. There aren't enough rows in your sample data to model interactions, but these would make things more complex.

Comment: Thanks. The DV is not count data. It can theoretically be any positive integer (but is <350 empirically)

Comment: So just to clarify, this would work, only assuming the IVs are independent of each other? If not (which doesn't seem to be the case with my data), this doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know which interactions your real data has, or how feasible this method would be for your real data. It works with the example set, but if the example is not representative of your real data, it's going to be difficult to give you a solution using only that sample. Details matter here I'm afraid - including the types of data, the distribution of the DV, and the interactions.